# Problems automatically creating a mysql database so it can be used on a fresh computer using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to automatically create the database and table so the website i am creating can be used on a fresh version of XXAMP. At the moment I used PHP myadmin to create the table. however when it loads on a fresh version of XXAMP the database will not be saved on the fresh computer. Therefore im trying to create PHP to automatically create the database and table so content can be added. This is my attempt at the moment but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "contentdatabase";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // sql to create table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE items
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    itemName text NULL,
    itemDescription text NULL,
    itemPrice float NULL,
    itemStock smallint(6) NULL,
    itemImage VARCHAR(100)  NULL,
    )";

    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Table items created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: `itemImage VARCHAR(100)  NULL,` <= remove that comma. You're also missing a bracket for `)";` or just remove it.

Comment: you've got exceptions turned on, so you should have gotten one thrown by that comma syntax error, and spit out by the `catch` block...

Comment: Here is a hint - run `SHOW CREATE TABLE items` on your master database.  Take the query result and copy that directly into your code.

Comment: How about instead of auto-regenerating an empty database every time, you export the database and import it on the other PC when you switch the files from one to the other? For this you could use the "export" function of PhpMyAdmin and check the "Create database" option. Then copy with the files and "import" on the other PC. This keeps your data in the DB. Also, to expedite this process, you could add a version control method (git or mercurial) into your development process. This adds versioning (so task-by-task) playback when needed and easier up-/downloading of all files.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is known as database migration, and there are some frameworks available for it, please take a look at [this](https://phinx.org/) which is a framework focused in DB migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the corresponding part of your code with the below. I have added comments in the relevant places. Remove the comments before running the code

```
// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE items ( //yours lacks this opening parentheses
id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
itemName text NULL,
itemDescription text NULL,
itemPrice float NULL,
itemStock smallint(6) NULL,
itemImage VARCHAR(100)  NULL //I have removed the last comma (,)
)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! 
I have got this semi working now thankfully! I can now create a new database and table. However I am now getting this error but i guess its some sort of if statement i need to add.

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'item' already existsCREATE DATABASE contentdatabase1
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1007 Can't create database 'contentdatabase1'; database exists

Comment: when doing a `CREATE DATABASE` or a `CREATE TABLE`, you might want to add a `IF NOT EXISTS` to check if whatever you're creating is already created or not. Take a look [MySQL Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-database.html)

Comment: It means you've already created a database with that name, so you probably need to do `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS`